Atomic chess ending rules query
This is a question about the rules of atomic chess.
I just mated my opponent in this variant, but the game didn't conclude at that conventional means of ending a game, and, instead continued to another half move ply in which the result was turned around.
Link to game: https://lichess.org/OynFjCTo/black
Could someone please explain this to me clearly?

Is there a link to the game you can share?

Thank you very much Mr secret agent, here is the link: https://lichess.org/OynFjCTo/black - as you can see, explosion was an option, but mate was "more elegant".

your opponent checkmated your king without you realizing it ... so your king was captured on your opponent's turn ... it's like that with any other game, but the actual capture is skipped, because it is pointless

Without mentioning of the site or ruleset under which this was played and a reference of the game this is hard to answer.
My best guess is that you "checkmated" your opponent, who however was able to explode your king with a capture. Usually in atomic chess, e.g., on lichess, checkmate only ends the game if the opponent can't capture the king immediately.

Thank you Fabian for your sketch outline, please see link in the commentary to the OP for the intrinsic details.
